# Deleting an event in llama

Tags: llama

I'm trying to figure out how to use Llama. However, I'm having difficulty figuring out something that seems like it should be obvious. Namely, how do I delete an event in Llama once I have defined it?

If I'm missing something obvious, I apologise.

Answer (score 0):

A few seconds after posting this, I found the following article:
[Make Your Smartphone Even Smarter](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/make-your-smartphone-even-smarter.htm), which says:

> You can copy, edit or disable an event, or delete it when you don't need, by touching and holding an item on the list of events.

This works, but in my opinion is not obvious. Also, I didn't find this in the official documentation. I looked. If it is in there, and I missed it, I can delete the question.

Comment: It might not be obvious *to a new user* – but as the equivalent to clicking with the right mouse button, that's how things work in many Android places ;)

Comment: @Izzy I'll bear that in mind. Should I delete the question?

Comment: I see no need to do that. Guess other new users might feel the same confusion, so it helps them.